# add an existing button to the action bar(show popup button)

Tags: android

I made an pause button which opens a popup with 3 buttons, Resume,Music on/off,Reset.

My problem is the button is on the screen and it takes some place and it's also ugly.. I want to put this button on the action bar.. how can I do it?

Here is my button:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/show_popup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/YouLost"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="@drawable/pausesign" />
```

Here is the popup dialog code:

```
 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
    button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    p = new Point();
    p.x = location[0];
    p.y = location[1]; }
 private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
    int popupWidth = 2000;
    int popupHeight = 1200;
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
    popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    int OFFSET_X = 60;
    int OFFSET_Y = 60;
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);
    Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
    Button restart = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.restart);
    final Button music = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.music);
    musicstop = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.musicstop);
    musicstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    music.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              mPlayer.pause(); 
              musicstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              music.setVisibility(View.GONE);}  });
    musicstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {       
              musicstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              music.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPlayer.start(); }  });
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        popup.dismiss(); }  });
    restart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup.dismiss();
            highscore_int.setText("");

            YouLost.setText("Game restarted"); 
            counter=0;
            TimeCounter=0;
            TimeCounter1=0;
            TimeCounter2=0;
            TimeCounter3=0;
            TimeCounter4=0;
            changingTextView.setText(""+counter); 
            button6.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(TimeCounter, TimeCounter, TimeCounter));   
            button5.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(TimeCounter1*2, TimeCounter1*2, TimeCounter1*2));  
            button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(TimeCounter2*3, TimeCounter2*3, TimeCounter2*3));  
            button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(TimeCounter3*4, TimeCounter3*4, TimeCounter3*4));  
            button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(TimeCounter4*5, TimeCounter4*5, TimeCounter4*5));  
            mPlayer.start();
            } });
    }
```

How can I add this button to the action bar?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: @IllegalArgument not working to me, I did as written:

 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:BlueTAP="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh"
    BlueTAP:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/pausesign" />
</menu>

Comment: Your activity should extend actionbaractivity have you done that

Comment: @IllegalArgument what do you mean?